# Dynamic DNS service allowing to define the IP address

Tags: dynamic-dns

Is there a dynamic DNS service that allows you to specify the IP address to point to (instead of pointing to the IP address making the request)?

We use dynamic DNS in our mobile application development.  We install a version of our app on a phone that points to a dynamic DNS address, which we can then change to point to whichever environment we want to test against without reinstalling the app.

All of the dynamic DNS services I have checked update the IP address to the IP address making the request.  This works fine for servers with a public IP address.  When we're working within our intranet, the IP address seen by the dynamic DNS server is not the internal IP address.  We'd like to be able to define the internal IP address to the dynamic DNS address.

We'd prefer a free service, but a pay service is also acceptable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, most dynamic DNS services support providing the IP address to set as the "myip" request parameter in the 'dyndns2' protocol update request.  This request parameter is supported by at least the [Dyn API](http://dyn.com/support/developers/api/perform-update/), [No-IP API](http://www.noip.com/integrate/request) and [DNSdynamic API](https://www.dnsdynamic.org/api.php).

This parameter is probably not supported by most dynamic DNS clients, but performing the request is very easy from the command line:

```
curl "https://username:password@dynupdate.no-ip.com/nic/update?hostname=mytest.testdomain.com&myip=1.2.3.4"
```

Answer (score 0):

DynDNS offered such a thing (at least they did; never tried to use a local IP address though; with their recent changes it's rather limited and I think you might no longer be able to get such freely defined addresses).

As an alternative: Don't you have any way to set the DNS server your phone is using? That would probably be the fastest way to change this, cause you'd be able to route requests locally.

Also keep in mind DNS caching, which might screw this up for you as a "quick" solution.

As an alternative: Use a fixed local address where you simply switch port forwarding to a different IP (e.g. through ssh tunnels). This would also prevent any caching issues.